# Finding an element in an array of structs using bsearch

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, bsearch

So I have an array of structures called conj_gms and what I want to find a specific `jogo`, given its `nome`.

Structure:

```
typedef struct jogo
{
    int id;
    char equipas[2][1024];
    int pont[2];
    char nome[MAX_CHARS];
} jogo;
```

For example i have jogo with

```
nome: ucl ,
equipas[0]: fcb,
equipas[1]: bvb,
pont[0]: 2,
pont[1]
```

at the index 1 of conj_jogs, if i search for the string UCL i want the id of the jogo with that name, after using bsearch, which is 1.

So to this i made a function that creates a jogo and atributted them to position in conj_jgs.

The problem is that when i use bsearch i get a segmentation faul

Program:

```
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CHARS 1024

static int id = 0;

typedef struct jogo
{
    int id;
    char equipas[2][1024];
    int pont[2];
    char nome[MAX_CHARS];
} jogo;

jogo make_game(char nome_jg[],char team1[],char team2[],int score1,int score2)
{
    jogo novo_jogo = {0};
    novo_jogo.id = id;
    strcpy(novo_jogo.equipas[0],team1);
    strcpy(novo_jogo.equipas[1],team2);
    strcpy(novo_jogo.nome,nome_jg);
    novo_jogo.pont[0] = score1;
    novo_jogo.pont[1] = score2;
    return novo_jogo;
}

int compare(const void *s, const void *d) {
    return strncmp(s, ((const jogo *)d)->nome, sizeof(((jogo *)0)->nome));
}

int main()
{
    int i; jogo* result;
    jogo conj_gms[MAX_CHARS];
    conj_gms[0] = make_game("DK","fcb","bvb",2,1);
    id++;
    conj_gms[1] = make_game("Elc","barca","rma",1,2);
    id++;
    conj_gms[2] = make_game("Class","fcp","slb",1,3);
    id++;
    conj_gms[3] = make_game("derby","slb","scp",4,1);
    id++;
    result = bsearch("Elc",conj_gms, 4, sizeof(jogo),compare);
    printf("found at index: %d",result->id);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(((jogo *)0)->nome)` is wrong, you should use `strlen` instread.

Comment: i still get a segmentation fault, so whats wrong?

Comment: `bsearch` expects the array to be sorted.  Your comparison function looks at the `nome` fields, and the `nome`s are not in order:  "DK", "Elc", "Class", "derby".  You want:  "Class", "DK", "Elc", "derby".  Note that "derby" is at the end because, with the default rules C uses, lowercase letters come after uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the array of structures shall be sorted by the value of the data member `nome`. Your array of structures is not sorted. Otherwise you have to use a linear search.

And  secondly you have to check the returned pointer of the call of `bsearch`

```
result = bsearch( "Elc", conj_gms, 4, sizeof(jogo),compare);
if ( result ) printf("found at index: %d",result->id);
```

As the array is not sorted by the data member `nome` then the returned pointer is equal to `NULL`.

Within the comparison function it is enough to use the function strcmp instead of the function strncmp

```
return strcmp(s, ((const jogo *)d)->nome );
```

If to sort the array

```
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CHARS 1024

static int id = 0;

typedef struct jogo
{
    int id;
    char equipas[2][1024];
    int pont[2];
    char nome[MAX_CHARS];
} jogo;

jogo make_game(char nome_jg[],char team1[],char team2[],int score1,int score2)
{
    jogo novo_jogo = {0};
    novo_jogo.id = id;
    strcpy(novo_jogo.equipas[0],team1);
    strcpy(novo_jogo.equipas[1],team2);
    strcpy(novo_jogo.nome,nome_jg);
    novo_jogo.pont[0] = score1;
    novo_jogo.pont[1] = score2;
    return novo_jogo;
}

int cmp(const void *s, const void *d) {
    return strcmp( ((const jogo *)s)->nome, ((const jogo *)d)->nome );
}

int compare(const void *s, const void *d) {
    return strcmp(s, ((const jogo *)d)->nome );
}

int main()
{
    jogo* result;
    jogo conj_gms[MAX_CHARS];
    conj_gms[0] = make_game("DK","fcb","bvb",2,1);
    id++;
    conj_gms[1] = make_game("Elc","barca","rma",1,2);
    id++;
    conj_gms[2] = make_game("Class","fcp","slb",1,3);
    id++;
    conj_gms[3] = make_game("derby","slb","scp",4,1);
    id++;

    qsort( conj_gms, 4, sizeof( jogo ), cmp );
    result = bsearch( "Elc", conj_gms, 4, sizeof(jogo),compare);
    if ( result ) printf("found at index: %d",result->id);
}
```

then you will get the expected result

```
found at index: 1
```

If you want to find an element of the array by some prefix then the comparison function can look like

```
int compare(const void *s, const void *d) {
    return strncmp(s, ((const jogo *)d)->nome, strlen( s ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you should change the line

```
result = bsearch("Elc",conj_gms, 4, sizeof(jogo),compare);
```

to

```
jogo const* result = bsearch("Elc",conj_gms, 4, sizeof(jogo),compare);
```